# What is Pre-Defined component?

Tags: vb.net

Hope you can help. 
I'm sort of new to computer programming, but I have experience with programming [just self taught] and I'm working on Unit for QA Apprenticeship and there few questions that are not making sense [City & Guilds fault] Anyhow..

Unit - Designing and Developing event drive computer programs using VB

1. select & use pre-defined components specialising as required
2. identify the set of events that invoke behaviour of components and other programmer elements.
3. specify the behaviour of components and other program elements to allow efficient implementation, selecting appropriate data types, data and file structures and algorithms.

These probably makes sense, but as English is not my primary language, I think I'm missing the meaning.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell without some context. But they probably mean code that has been developed by a third party (e.g. a library or toolkit).

Comment: That's all I got; It's Design Event Driven program to address loosely-defined problems and then thats' the question... Thanks!

Comment: This might be marked as off-topic as it isnt a problem you have about specific code. Sorry - see my answer - quick! :)

Comment: @DavidWilson thanks,I got it sorted.. You were right.. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they mean things like buttons or a class.

For the second task maybe they mean the events that the component responds to - click, mouseover, hover - or methods and functions within a class component- that kind of thing.

The third task is so vague - you need to ask your tutor for more info.

Here is a definition of a component - look at section 2 on OOP programming .. http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/component

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting for a response from Tutor now!